# Removing White Space from a Regex result

Tags: regex

I have a Regex query that works to find the data:

Matching a 9 digit number (not more, not less), with some being separated by a space or `-`.

```
(?:\d{9}\s)|(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})
```

The problem I have with the results is the `(?:\d{9}\s)` returns the trailing space character, or tab, or new line - but it prevents a 9 digit result being returned from a 10 digit number sequence.

How do I change this to either remove the white space in the results, or work to just pickup the `\d{9}` (Whilst not returning 9 digits from a 10 or more digit number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary:

```
(?:\d{9}\b)|(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})
//   ___^^
```

According to comment, OP needs also a word boundary before:

```
(?:\b\d{9}\b)|(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})
```

and probably for the other part of alternative:

```
(?:\b\d{9}\b)|\b(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})\b
```

The whole regex becomes:

```
\b(?:\d{9}|(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3}))\b
```

Comment: Thanks Toto, it does remove the trailing character - didn't know about the \b command, this will come in handy. This returns the last 9 characters of a 10 character string, which I don't want to match in this case.

Comment: @warfy: Add also a word boudary  `\b` before `(?:\b\d{9}\b)|(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})`

Answer (score 1):

If you change `\s` to `(?=\s)`, which is a positive lookahead:

```
(?:\d{9})(?=\s)
```

It looks like it might solve your issue, but I don't know all your requirements.

Comment: @warfy If this answered your question, please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer (there is a gray check mark under the up/down voting arrows)